# Get Python script state from another script

Tags: python

I have a python3 program that does some stuff and a Pyramid app that allows users to interact with the program's database. Say, my program may be busy with 2 kinds of activity: 'Task1' and 'Task2'. I would like to be able to get the current activity (better with some other additional info) from my Pyramid app and show it to users. What is the best way to do that? If possible, I would prefer to avoid multithreading and all that stuff.

The only idea I have in mind is having a special file on disk where my program writes it's activity whenever it changes. But I guess that solution doesn't shine at performance, not to mention other drawbacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have three options:

> 1 - As you said, use a special file .. (but that's not practical and kinda 1990 stuff ..)
>   2 - Use a special process for threads communication using multithreading .. (a complicated solution for a simple language)
>   3 - Use the database, and put a special key with a special value to indicate whether the value in the database key you choose to put your communications in have changed or not .. Better be json formatted .. (I think that's the most practical and the easiest solution)

Comment: Thanks, somewhy I missed the third variant. Sounds quite simple and practical.